# Issue Aligning Text with the Image Using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, migradoc

I am having header in this format --

"**Heading**"   "Image" "Title"

Below is the code snippet i am using to achieve this -

```
    Paragraph header = section.Headers.Primary.AddParagraph("Heading");            
    header.Format.Font.Bold = true;
    header.AddTab();
    Image image = header.AddImage("../../Images/logo.png");
    image.Height = Unit.FromMillimeter(6);
    header.AddFormattedText("Title", TextFormat.NotBold);
```

I need to align my "Image" and "Title" in such a way that title is vertically centrally aligned with respect to image's height, how can i achieve this ?

Any pointers/code snippet is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a table to fit all the information in a certain structure:

```
// create document
Document MigraDokument = new Document();

// create section. 
Section section = MigraDokument.AddSection();            
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;

// create a table
Table t = section.AddTable();
// size to use for the image and the image cell in the table
int size = 6;

// create 3 columns
Column column_header = t.AddColumn("6cm");
column_header.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

Column column_image = t.AddColumn(Unit.FromMillimeter(size));
column_image.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

Column column_text = t.AddColumn("4cm");
column_text.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

// Add 1 row to fill it with the content
Row r = t.AddRow();

// add you Header
Paragraph header = r.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Heading");
header.Format.Font.Bold = true;
header.AddTab();

// add the image            
Image image = r.Cells[1].AddImage("../../logo.png"); 
image.Height = Unit.FromMillimeter(size);

// Add your Title
r.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Title");

// allign all of them
r.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
r.Cells[1].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
r.Cells[2].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

In my document the result looks the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the approach helped in getting the desired result hence i will accept as an answer , would have been happier if it could have been achieved without using table & by using some alignment properties of "Image" & "Para Text"(if any)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MongZhu for suggesting the table way , posting the code snippet that i am using now just for future reference.

```
        Table table = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();
        table.AddColumn("11cm");
        table.AddColumn("2cm");
        table.AddColumn("8cm");

        Row row = table.AddRow();
        row.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        Paragraph header = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Heading");
        header.Format.Font.Bold = true;                        
        Image image = row.Cells[1].AddImage("../../Images/logo.png");
        image.Height = Unit.FromMillimeter(6);
        row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Title");
```